Launching via cmaketools ignores launch.json
I'm trying to build and run a C++ project with certain arguments that make it quicker to test a feature I'm working on. For some reason, the CMakeTools extension in VSCode doesn't seem to recognize my launch.json configuration file, meaning I have to constantly make sure I'm launching using the right button.
This is the launch button I WANT to click, that ignores my launch.json configuration:

Meanwhile, the button I'm forced to click, as it actually follows my launch.json configuration>

How do I make it so that both buttons follow my launch.json configuration? Beyond that, when following it, how do I set a default configuration in my list so I don't have to keep picking one every time I run it?

ask one question per question post.
